# give an array to a function, exclamation mark?

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to give an array to a function. I finish to success to arrive to this solution :

```
test_arr() {
  local a="${!1}"
  for i in ${a[@]}
  do
    echo $i
    printf '\n'
  done
}

arr=("lol 1" "lol 2" "lol 3");
test_arr arr[@]
```

However there is two issues with that : there is a copy via the `local` variable. So I would be able to use `$1` directly in the for loop, and I do not understand the purpose of `${!1}`. What does mean the `!`?

Another problem is that for my shell, there is 6 elements instead of 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just pass values of an array to a function, you can do this:

```
test_arr() {
  for i in "$@"; do
    echo $i
    printf '\n'
  done
:
}

arr=("lol 1" "lol 2" "lol 3")
test_arr "${arr[@]}"
```

`"${arr[@]}"` will pass all values properly delimited to the function where we can access them through `$@` (all arguments).

`!` you've asked about is used for indirect reference. I.e. `"${!1}"` is not value of the first argument, but value of the variable whose name is what the value of the first argument was.

---

I could have missed something, but it seems like wanting to combine indirection and access all items of indirectly referenced array at the same time would be asking a little too much from shell so I've conjured mighty `eval` (good reason to start being cautious) to help us out a bit. I've hacked this which allows you to pass array name to a function and then access its items based on that name as seen in the first argument of the function, but it's not pretty and that alone should be enough of a discouragement to not do it. It does create a local variable / array as your example assuming there was some reason to want that.

```
test_arr() {
  local a
  eval a=(\"\$\{$1\[@\]\}\")
  for i in "${a[@]}"; do
          echo $i
  done
}

arr=("lol 1" "lol 2" "lol 3")
test_arr arr
```

Comment: Maybe I would have to be more accurate, but I want to pass more than one array... (however, what is the difference between `$@` and `%*` ?)

Comment: Short version: `"$@"` will be individual strings for each argument, `"$*"` would be a single string with concatenation of all arguments. Long version would be the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters). :)